# Dynamically generate html and validate as well

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, .net, jquery-ui

I'm trying to add TextBox ID="tbComment" when the date picked if less than the current date on the client side before hitting the submit button.

Which way would be better to go for it? I have tried going the javascript way but i don't know why but the page failed to load.

I know there is "onTextChanged" event for a textbox when fired we can call a javascript, but how does one implement it to add html when the date selected is less than the current date on the client side?

```
<table class="sidemenu" id="BudgetDetailsTable" align="left" border="0" runat="server"
                    width="100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td width="20%">
                            Project Period Start Date:
                        </td>
                        <td width="80%">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtFromDate" title="Click to select date" Style="cursor: pointer"
                                runat="server" CssClass="textboxunderline" EnableViewState="true" TabIndex="1"></asp:TextBox><asp:RequiredFieldValidator
                                    ID="rfvFromDate" runat="server" ErrorMessage="<br /> - Please provide Start Date."
                                    ControlToValidate="txtFromDate">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator><asp:CompareValidator
                                        ID="cvFromDate" runat="server" ErrorMessage="<br /> - Please provide valid From date. From date should be before End date."
                                        ControlToValidate="txtFromDate" Display="dynamic" Type="Date" Operator="LessThanEqual"
                                        ControlToCompare="txtEndDate">*
                                    </asp:CompareValidator>
                                    <asp:CustomValidator ID="cvBeforeDate" runat="server" ErrorMessage="<br /> - Please provide a reason to for adding a sheet having start date before today's date."
                                OnServerValidate="cvCheck_StartDate">* </asp:CustomValidator>

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="20%">
                            Project Period End Date:
                        </td>
                        <td width="80%">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtEndDate" title="Click to select date" Style="cursor: pointer"
                                runat="server" CssClass="textboxunderline"  EnableViewState="true" TabIndex="2"></asp:TextBox><asp:RequiredFieldValidator
                                    ID="rfvEndDate" runat="server" ErrorMessage=" <br /> - Please provide End Date."
                                    ControlToValidate="txtEndDate">* </asp:RequiredFieldValidator><asp:CompareValidator
                                        ID="cvEndDate" runat="server"  ErrorMessage="<br /> - Please provide valid End date. End date should be larger than From date."
                                        ControlToValidate="txtEndDate"   Display="dynamic" Type="Date" Operator="GreaterThanEqual"
                                        ControlToCompare="txtFromDate">*
                                    </asp:CompareValidator>
                            <asp:CustomValidator ID="cvDateMonth" runat="server"  ErrorMessage="<br /> - Please provide start day and month different to end day and month."
                                  ClientValidationFunction="cvDateMonth_ServerValidate">*</asp:CustomValidator>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="20%" >
                            <asp:Label ID="Reason" CssClass="sidemenu" runat="server" Visible="False">Reason:</asp:Label>                                    
                        </td>
                        <td width="80%" >
                            <asp:TextBox ID="tbComment" runat="server"  Visible="False" TabIndex="3" 
                                CausesValidation="false" Width="646px"  Enabled="False"></asp:TextBox><asp:RequiredFieldValidator
                                ID="rfvReason" runat="server"   CssClass="requiredStar" ErrorMessage="<br /> - Please provide a reason to submit a proposal who's start date is before Today's date."
                                ControlToValidate="tbComment">* </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

                        </td>
                    </tr>
```

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/144113/JavaScript-Date-Validation

Comment: What's your Javascript code? What error is it "popping"? Could you indent the code snippet better?

Comment: the error is basically that the form fails to load when I try to add the JavaScript and call the function ontextchange

Comment: That's just saying "the error is that it didn't work". Be specific, include code, say what happened (including errors from the Javascript console, if any) and what you expected to happen. Preferrably make a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) with a plain-HTML test case of what you tried to do.

Comment: well basically what I'm trying to do is validate the date entered by a user as soon as the date is picked if it's before today's date and if the date is before today, it should generate a textbox as an additional field to be entered in the form. 

I shall post the script that I was using here soon.

Answer (score 0):

You can use (element).innerHTML to directly modify the element's source code. This shouldn't give you an error, but perhaps someone else has a more high-level method?